# Flex 3 loading background color

Tags: flex3, colors, background, loading

During loading of a Flex 3 built application, it always shows this blue-grayish background color. I've tried a handful of tips, building preloaders etc, and all that works, but even before the preloaders kick in, that blue-grayish color is displayed. I've tried lots of ways to change it, like editing compiler options, setting background image to an empty string etc, but nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue and spent a good hour looking for a solution.  To the best of my understanding, the blueish-grey color is directly set from the HTML file generated from index.template.hmtl.  There is a binding in that file under `<param name="bgcolor" value="{bgcolor}" />` that sets the background color.  I'm assuming that bgcolor should be pulled from the backgroundColor you set in your Application.  And you could also just try hard coding your value in that param also.

Comment: Indeed! I was just about to come back and write the same solution because I just figured it out yesterday... The whole reason of the problem is exactly as you describe. Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

To get past the default 'bluish' background on loading to say...white, add this to the compiler arguments: -default-background-color #ffffff.